# Jenkins inheritance-plugin: how about build steps in the middle

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How do I manage the order of execution of the build steps defined in parent and child? Are build steps defined in parent always be executed first, then child? e.g. I have a few common build steps, but they are in the middle, how do I define the parent and child?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the [inheritance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin) you better use [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) where you can control the flow of all steps and even pass all parent properties to its child jobs.